# Using the lubridate package to merge dates and its associated values in R

Tags: r, lubridate

This is the second time I'm posting with regards to the same dataset. This time, I'm having trouble using the function `ceiling_date` from the package `lubridate`.

Here's a sample of my dataset:

```
> head(dataraw)
                Time ACTIVITY_X ACTIVITY_Y ACTIVITY_Z
 1: 6/19/18 10:40:00         60         74         95
 2: 6/19/18 10:41:20         62         63         88
 3: 6/19/18 10:42:40         60         56         82
 4: 6/19/18 10:44:00         66         61         90
 5: 6/19/18 10:45:20         60         53         80
 6: 6/19/18 10:46:40         57         40         70
 7: 6/19/18 10:48:00         54         41         68
 8: 6/19/18 10:49:20         52         49         71
 9: 6/19/18 10:50:40         61         49         78
10: 6/19/18 10:52:00         93         32         98
11: 6/19/18 10:53:20         80         54         97
12: 6/19/18 10:54:40         73         39         83
13: 6/19/18 10:56:00         47         37         60
14: 6/19/18 10:57:20         51         55         75
15: 6/19/18 10:58:40         51         60         79
16: 6/19/18 11:00:00         14         13         19
17: 6/19/18 11:01:20          0          0          0
18: 6/19/18 11:02:40         13          3         13
19: 6/19/18 11:04:00         20         10         22
20: 6/19/18 11:05:20         13          6         14
```

And this is how I would like to transform my data:

```
                Time     x   y   z
1: 2018-06-19 10:40:00  60  74  95
2: 2018-06-19 10:44:00 188 180 260
3: 2018-06-19 10:48:00 171 134 218
4: 2018-06-19 10:52:00 206 130 247
5: 2018-06-19 10:56:00 200 130 240
6: 2018-06-19 11:00:00 116 128 173
7: 2018-06-19 11:04:00  33  13  35
8: 2018-06-19 11:08:00  13   6  14
```

Where time is taken every 240 seconds (4 minutes) instead of 80 seconds (1:20 minutes) as in `dataraw`. The values for `ACTIVITY_X`, `ACTIVITY_Y` and `ACTIVITY_Z` are summed to fit the longer 4 minute interval.

Below's the code I've been using for this matter. This works for the sample I've posted, but when used on the full `dataraw` dataset I've warning messages and errors as seen below:

```
> sampleinput<-na.omit(dataraw)
> names(sampleinput)[1]<-"Time"
> sampleinput$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(sampleinput$Time))
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion 
> X <- data.table(sampleinput)
> X$tgroup <- lubridate::ceiling_date(X$Time, '4 mins')
Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
> X[, list( x = sum(ACTIVITY_X), 
+           y = sum(ACTIVITY_Y), 
+           z =sum(ACTIVITY_Z) ), by = list (tgroup)]
Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'tgroup' not found
```

Does this relate to syntax or coding errors? If that helps, the full `dataraw` dataset is available [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gt5Ju1ouNQ2MV61T7ov3pg410f-BgDOe/view), as it's too big to be posted as `dput()`

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. Date parsing has failed. See the solution below:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data <- read.table("41361_sensor_converted.txt", sep="\t", header=TRUE)

data %>% 
 mutate(
  Time      = mdy_hms(data$Time),
  TimeGroup = ceiling_date(Time, '4 mins') ) %>%
 group_by(TimeGroup) %>% 
 summarise(
  x = sum(ACTIVITY_X),
  y = sum(ACTIVITY_Y),
  z = sum(ACTIVITY_Z) )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used your code for the full dataset `dataraw` but I still have an error message: ```> dataraw %>% 
+   mutate(
+     Time      = mdy_hms(dataraw$Time),
+     TimeGroup = ceiling_date(Time, '4 mins') ) %>%
+   group_by(TimeGroup) %>% 
+   summarise(
+     x = sum(x),
+     y = sum(y),
+     z = sum(z) )
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'x' not found.``` Any idea on how to fix this problem?

Comment: See the update. It works with the original file and colnames ACTIVITY_X,...